# Filling array in struct pointer in C

Tags: c

Hey there I have a little question:

I defined a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char key [50][50];
    char literal [50][50];
    double numeral [50];
} skill_data;
```

And a function:

```
skill_data *
mongoc_fetchSkillParameter (const bson_t *recipe, char *skill_id)
{
    bson_iter_t iter;
    bson_iter_t child1;
    bson_iter_t child2;
    bson_iter_t child3;
   
    int i = 0;
    skill_data *parameterset;
    
    bson_iter_init(&iter, recipe);
   
    if (bson_iter_find (&iter, "Skills") && BSON_ITER_HOLDS_ARRAY (&iter) && bson_iter_recurse (&iter, &child1)) {
        printf ("Accessing sub-key \"%s\"\n", bson_iter_key (&iter));
        bson_iter_next (&child1);
        printf ("Accessing sub-key \"%s\"\n", bson_iter_key (&child1));
    }

    if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_DOCUMENT (&child1) && bson_iter_recurse (&child1, &child2)) {
        bson_iter_find(&child2, "ParameterSet");
        printf ("Accessing sub-key \"%s\"\n", bson_iter_key (&child2)); 
    }

    if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_DOCUMENT (&child2) && bson_iter_recurse (&child2, &child3)) {
        i = 0;
        while (bson_iter_next (&child3)) {
            strcpy (parameterset->key[i], bson_iter_key (&child3));
            if (bson_iter_type (&child3) == 0x01 || 0x10 || 0x12){
                parameterset->numeral[i] = bson_iter_as_double (&child3);
            }
            else if (bson_iter_type (&child3) == 0x02){
                strcpy (parameterset->literal[i], bson_iter_utf8 (&child3, NULL));
            }
            i++;    
        }
    }
 
    return parameterset;
}
```

I am trying to fill the arrays in the struct and then pass the pointer to the main function. The functions bson_iter_utf8() and bson_iter_key() both return pointer on a string as far as I understand it:

```
const char *
bson_iter_utf8 (const bson_iter_t *iter, uint32_t *length);
```

It worked while initializing simple arrays but now embedded in a struct pointer I seem to have trouble. Can somebody help me? :) Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you declare a pointer to `skill_data` but it's not actually pointing at any allocated memory:

```
skill_data *parameterset;
```

Alternative methods for fixing this problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

```
skill_data *parameterset = malloc(sizeof *parameterset);
```

or

```
skill_data *parameterset = calloc(1, sizeof *parameterset); // zero-initialized
```

Note: When you're done with the pointer, you should call `free` on it.

Comment: Yes I totally forgot to allocate memory, that was the mistake. Thank you very much!!